# Installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on DELL Vostro 3445 but display is jerky

Tags: display

I have installed ubutu 14.04.1 on dell vostro 3445, but screen transitions, movements are jerky (not smooth). What ca be the remedy?

Comment: What processor and graphics card do you have?

Comment: AMD E6010 4th Gen / 4GB RAM

Comment: Graphics:
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU E2-4000 with R2 Graphics]

Comment: Can you add to your question, the output of the command `glxinfo | grep renderer`?  If glxinfo does not run, you will need to execute `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem.
Step 1. I opened the system settings > software updates
Step 2. Clicked additional drivers tab ... it took some time to fetch the list
Step 3. My computer was using X.org Xserver -AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg (open source code). I changed it to Video driver for AMD graphic accelators from fglx (proprietary)

Now my problem is gone. Even HD videos are running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

As well as RAM and SWAP, you need to make sure that you have the proper drivers installed. Ubuntu comes with compatibility with most graphics systems, however, for those that don't come compatible "Out of the Box" you may need to locate an install the correct drivers.